# Download GitHub repositories list matching a topic?

Tags: git, github, command-line, github-api

Is there any way to download a list of projects matching a GitHub topic?
For example if I write:

https://github.com/topics/haskell

in a web browser, returns a page with GitHub projects related with Haskell. I read their GitHub API but they don't seem to implement the feature: https://developer.github.com/v3/

Also the endpoint https://api.github.com/ does not seem to contain any option. All I get for my attempts like https://api.github.com/topics/haskell is:

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

Comment: Wouldn’t this be better asked on github?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct GitHub API endpoint for topics is: `https://api.github.com/search/topics` and you need to provide the topic query in the `q` query parameter.  Here's an example query directly from the [API documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-topics):

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.mercy-preview+json' 'https://api.github.com/search/topics?q=ruby+is:featured'
```

And here's an example looking for your search topic 'haskell':

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.mercy-preview+json' 'https://api.github.com/search/topics?q=haskell'
```

See:
    https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-topics

Comment: but the result does not contain a list of repositories - it is a lisf of subtopics

Answer (score 5):

If you want to search repositories matching a topic, use [`/search/repositories`](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories) with `topic` properties :

```
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.mercy-preview+json" \
    https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=topic:haskell
```

You have to provide the `application/vnd.github.mercy-preview+json` while it's still in developer preview :

> Note: The topics property for repositories on GitHub is currently
>   available for developers to preview. To view the topics property in
>   calls that return repository results, you must provide a custom media
>   type in the Accept header:
>
> application/vnd.github.mercy-preview+json

Comment: Bertrand, is there now (in 2023) a way of listing all topics, ideally url -> its topics list ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"You can search for code globally across all of GitHub Enterprise, or search for code within a particular repository or organization. To search for code across all public repositories, you must be signed in to a GitHub Enterprise account."

This curl will only return tags or topics
curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.mercy-preview+json' 'https://api.github.com/search/topics?q=haskell'

Source: [https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.13/user/articles/searching-code#:~:text=You%20can%20search%20for%20code%20globally%20across%20all%20of%20GitHub,%22About%20searching%20on%20GitHub.%22](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.13/user/articles/searching-code#:%7E:text=You%20can%20search%20for%20code%20globally%20across%20all%20of%20GitHub,%22About%20searching%20on%20GitHub.%22)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GraphQL API to get the repositories in a topic.

Try it out at: https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer

```gql
query { 
  search(first: 10, type: REPOSITORY, query: "topic:databases") {
    repositoryCount
    nodes {
      ... on Repository {
        nameWithOwner
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  "data": {
    "search": {
      "repositoryCount": 831,
      "nodes": [
        {
          "nameWithOwner": ".../..."
        },
        {
          "nameWithOwner": ".../..."
        },
...
```

Caveat: You cannot use the GraphQL api to get the list of topics.

Topic querying is limited.

There is `Query.topic` to search for a single topic and `Repository.repositoryTopics`. `Topic.relatedTopics` exists as "A list of related topics, including aliases of this topic, sorted with the most relevant first. Returns up to 10 Topics.".